# Google Cloud Bigtable/HBase Result Iterable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I am testing performance using Google Cloud Bigtable with a table with 10M rows using the Java HBase API client.
For the following commands the performance is relatively fast

```
Scan scan = new Scan()
ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

(1e-3, or 1e-2 second range)

However when I use the foreach loop to get the contents of the row from the iterable:

```
for (Result row : scanner) {
    byte[] valueBytes = row.getRow();
```

(The above commands are generic as I'm pretty sure I used the correct rowkey filtering methods, as well as accounting for regions/tablets)

The row.getRow()/ row.getValue() is super fast

However, traversing the ResultScanner is super slow (like > 30 seconds)

I've been reading in the docs that using setCaching() should help speed things up, however according to Google Cloud Bigtable docs setCaching() is not implemented.
From the docs it reads:

**org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan#setCaching(int caching) are ignored**

My question is how can I increase speeds to read actual content from row objects (especially when traversing rows)?

Answer (score 0):

This performance is about what you can expect from a single scan on your table.  FWIW, there is already caching done under the covers, and the Cloud Bigtable client ignores settings on HBase Scan object.

If you want to speed up performance, you will have to read the table in parallel scans.  You can get some hints about your keyspace from [RegionLocator](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/RegionLocator.html).  You can further split the range for each region by calling [Bytes.split()](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/Bytes.html#split-byte:A-byte:A-int-).  Once you have those ranges, you can construct parallel reads.

Comment: I tried using your advice on using Bytes.split() to split the range based on a given region, and I noticed that splitting the regions appropriately result in faster reading scans, however if I used to large of a split I would get hundreds of milliseconds to read a split that had no records.  How does hbase divide the range into the splits.  I cannot find any documentation on this.  Also from what I have seen querying/fetching data, BigQuery seems to be more efficient than using BigTable even with parallelizing scans.  Is there something I am missing conceptually? (Sorry for the long comment)

Comment: Bytes.split() splits the start/stop solely based on in memory information.  It's not surprising that some splits would return no data.  In terms BigQuery (BQ) vs Cloud Bigtable (CBT), BQ was intended for full table scans, and BT was meant for different uses -- range scans, point lookups and frequent updates.

Comment: Also, should reading/scanning BigTable using GAE/Google Cloud offer significant performance/speedup compared to reading/scanning BigTable locally?

Comment: Running in GAE / GCE is definitely faster.  Accessing any Google Cloud service is faster from within the same zone.